# Eclipse AJDT - Error message "This method must return a result of type int" on Java aspect class

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, syntax-error, aspectj, ajdt

I'm using AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) Eclipse plugin.

I wrote the following advice:

```
package com.exemple.aop.aspect;

import com.exemple.aop.bean.impl.MyBeanImpl.Iface;



aspect MyAspect {
    
    // pointcut
    pointcut clientMethod(Iface p) : target(p) && call(String com.exemple.aop.bean.impl.MyBeanImpl$Client.doSomething());  
    
    // advice
    // **LINE JUST BELOW IS MARKED AS ERROR**
    after(Iface p) returning(Object x): clientMethod(p) {
        System.out.println("Returning from client method");
        System.out.println("Target: " + p);
        System.out.println("Return: " + x);
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test that works: traces are visible in the console.

However, when opening the Java file with the AspectJ/Java editor, my Eclipse UI shows an error at line "*after(Iface p) returning(Object x): clientMethod(p) {*"
It says:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - This method must return a result of type int
> - 2 AspectJ markers at this line

Note that the project is not marked with the error flag in the "Project explorer" view.

**Does any one know or as an idea why the Eclipse AJDT plugin shows the error "*This method must return a result of type int*"?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. Most likely, you are trying to open an aspect file in a java editor.

Comment: It's not the possibility you mention: I open the file with the "AspectJ/Java Editor".

Comment: Also, make sure that JDT weaving is enabled. If it is, then also look at your eclipse error log. And paste any relevant errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspect file was created as a Java Class (*MyAspect.java*).
You have to create it as a Aspect (*MyAspect.aj*).

Just do it via *New -> Other -> Aspect* with the same content.

You should have AspectJ plugin for Eclipse (AJDT)

That's it